# How to use one file value to another file in terraform

Tags: linux

I have two terraform file test1.tf and test2.tf.

My requirement is i have one value in test1.tf (e.g id=123). How to refer this id in the file test2.tf.

Please let us know how to do this in terraform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 2 files are in same project folder, you should be able to refer to resources in one another as "${resource_type.resource_name.attribute}" or example "${aws_iam_policy.my_policy.name}"

All files in the project are collapsed and merged before execution, so it is 1 project in totality.